# Selenium types email password incorrectly

Tags: python, selenium, safari

I'm writing a little Python program to automate the e-mail authentication process using selenium. Now, when I execute the program I always get the "email or password incorrect" message even if I'm **sure** that they are correct; I tried to execute the program line by line in the Python shell and I also changed the password to one without special characters just to be sure that selenium wasn't having problem with these specifically but without success so I think that somehow selenium is not "typing" the password correctly in the authentication form.

I'm using python 3.6; here's the code (without the real username and password for security reasons, of course).

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get("myEmailProvider")
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id("usernameDisplay")
emailElem.send_keys("myEmail")
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
passwordElem.send_keys("myEmailPassword")
passwordElem.submit()
```

Does anyone have any idea about why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when I used Selenium to enter username and password. I have noticed that It would sometimes "eat" letter of two. For example, instead of typing "password" it would type "passord" or something like that.

I tried to find why this is happening, but without luck, however, I found workaround for this.

I put these things into while loop. So in your example I would do:

```
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
while(passwordElem != "myEmailPassword")
    passwordElem.send_keys("myEmailPassword")
passwordElem.submit()code here
```

You can also put some limit how much times it can loop before It throws error, so you don't end up in infinite loop, but from my experience it send correct values in max 3 tries.

Answer (score 1):

To work around this the best approach is to fill the form data in via javascript:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("usernameDisplay").value="myEmail"')
```